# What is an Orphan point?

Tags: qgis, point

MY apologizes about the next doubt, but I can't understand what is an **orphan point**. I am using QGIS with a module to apply the Linear Reference System (the module is called "LRS"). During the Calibration step, I select the Linear layer and Point layer. After I go to "Errors" step and the module identifies the next errors:

> Not enough points
>   Orphan point

The question is: What is an orphan point?

**Solved**: The problem was solved. The id's of each layer must have the same ID.

Comment: Not sure about QGIS, but in abstract, an Orphan point is a point that is not connected to an edge (or a line). Thus it is considered not connected or does not belong to a particular  geographical network. To fix orphan points you should connect them to a line.

Comment: May be your point does not specify a line id or specify one that does not exist.